# Add images to a div programatically and align them horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 images and I want to add those images to a div programatically via javascript or jquery. What is the way to do it? Like I want the alignment to be 2 images in every. So, if there are 6 images, I want 3 rows, each row having 2 mages. Is it possible to without css via js or jquery only .

Also, I would like to add a double click handler to each image added. What is best way to it.

I am looping thru various images like :

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    if(elements[i].querySelector("img")) {
        var path = elements[i].querySelector("img").src;
        var newimage = document.createElement('img');  
        newimage.setAttribute('src', path);
        var div = document.getElementById("enclosingdiv");
        enclosingdiv.appendChild(newimage);
    }
}
```

Comment: No mention of the source for the image data here. *" Is it possible to with css"* yes and this is easy to research layout css. You are expected to do such basic research before asking questions here

Comment: image data comes out from the server . I have that with me. I meant is it possible to do without css ?

Comment: Won't get much help without more technical and code specific explanations than that. Strongly suggest you take some time to read through [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this-

```
       <div id="imagesDisplay">

       </div>

       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var elements = new Array("book2.jpg","book3.jpg","book4.jpg","book5.jpg");
            var noImages = 2; // 2 images per row
            var imgCount = 0; // will keep count of images per row
            var divHTML = ""; // will hold html tags to be dispalyed once the loop is complete i.e. all the images are added
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
                console.log(elements[i]);

            if( imgCount ===0 ) {
                divHTML += "<div class='row'>\n";
            }   
            divHTML += "<div class='col-md-6'><img src='images/"+elements[i]+"'></div>\n";
            imgCount++;

            if( imgCount === noImages) {
                imgCount = 0;
                divHTML += "</div>\n";
            }

        }

        $("#imagesDisplay").html(divHTML);
       });
        </script>
```